# How do I attach a click event handler to a particular candlestick generated using the plotly.NET library?

Tags: d3.js, f#, plotly.js, plotly.net

I'm just beginning to learn F# and I was wondering how to attach a **click event handler** to a particular candlestick rendered using the plotly.NET library at https://plotly.net/07_1_candlestick.html

Notice if you scroll down and *hover* your mouse pointer on a candlestick in one of the sample charts, it pops up with quantitative data for the candlestick.

How can I create a similar ***click*** event handler in F# which does some background tasks or creates additional pop-ups/windows for the user to interact with?

Comment: Is it possible to use Javascript to do what I am asking?

Comment: "FSharp.Plotly is a FSharp wrapper for Plotly.js."  According to https://csbiology.github.io/CSBlog/posts/WorkshopSeries_3_plotly.html#FSharp-Plotly

Comment: Does this mean the event handler will need to be written in javascript or FSharp?